# Are these independent? - $\chi^2$-test

Tags: statistics, independence, chi-squared

The below table gives us the number of books issued from a certain library on the various days of the week.

[image]

Test at $5\%$ level whether issuing book is a day dependent (Given $\chi_{5:0.05}=11.07$)

$$$$

We have to use the chi-square test of independence, right?

H0: Issuing book is a day independent.

H1: Issuing book is a day dependent.

The sum of the row is equal to $120+130+110+115+135+110=720$

We have $\chi_{5:0.05}=11.07$.

Which degrees of freedom do we have here?

Then we have to calculated the corresponding p-value, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert, so take my answer with a grain of salt, although I did study Chi-squared tests recently, however, I'm not certain it is the "best test", or I have "applied it in the best way", or whatever. But I feel like in statistics these things are arguable depending on your level. Anyway, this is how I would do it based on the OCR A-Level Further Maths Statistics syllabus.

Quoting from Further Maths OCR A Level Statistics:

> A constraint is a parameter in the model which is found from the data
> and then fixed to take the same value in the model. One constraint
> that is always required is the total frequency: you always want the
> total expected frequency to be the same as the observed frequency,
> otherwise you are not comparing the results fairly.

Our "model" is a table of expected frequencies where the numbers in each box are $120$, because that's what you would expect if the days are all independent.

Degrees of freedom = number of bins - number of constraints = $6-1$ (the total number of books) $=5.$

To be clear, there is $1$ constraint: the total number of books.

So *from the table of critical values*, the critical value is $\chi_{5:0.05}=11.07.$

Comparing the data with the observed frequencies, we get:

$\chi^2_{\text{calc}}=\frac{(120-120)^2}{120} + \frac{(130-120)^2}{120} + \frac{(110-120)^2}{120} + \frac{(115-120)^2}{120} + \frac{(135-120)^2}{120} + \frac{(110-120)^2}{120} = \ldots$

If $\chi^2_{\text{calc}} > 11.07$ then reject $H_0$ as there is significant evidence of dependence. If $\chi^2_{\text{calc}} < 11.07$ then accept $H_0$: there is no significant evidence of dependence.

You then should write a conclusion, putting your result into the context of the question, as you usually do with hypothesis tests.

I'm not sure what $p-$values have to do with this?

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for your answer!! :-)